# Metal iOS gives compile error

Tags: ios, swift, metal

```
import UIKit
import Metal
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var device: MTLDevice! = nil
var metalLayer: CAMetalLayer! = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    metalLayer = CAMetalLayer()          // 1
    metalLayer.device = device           // 2
    metalLayer.pixelFormat = .BGRA8Unorm // 3
    metalLayer.framebufferOnly = true    // 4
    metalLayer.frame = view.layer.frame  // 5
    view.layer.addSublayer(metalLayer)   // 6
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

When I have this in my ViewController.swift, I get the error "Use of undeclared type `CAMetalLayer`" even though I've imported Metal and QuartzCore. How can I get this code to work?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
[Simulator support is coming this year](https://twitter.com/gavkar/status/1135775206377549824) (2019)

**Pre Xcode 11/iOS 13**:
Metal code doesn't compile on the Simulator. Try compiling for a device.

Comment: I haven't even compiled for anything yet. This shows up right after I type that stuff in and just wait

Comment: Try selecting a device instead of the simulator in Xcode

Comment: This response doesn't answer the question, because there was no question, however it is a solution to the stated problem: the Simulator can't compile metal code. If you select a Device, the compile errors go away.

Comment: There is the implicit "How to fix it" question if you make a little effort.

Comment: In 2017, Metal code compiles on the simulator. This person followed an online tutorial, which I also do. I get the same error. The Metal game template compiles and run on the simulator, but the code doesn't keep CAMetalLayer in it.     Edit: CAMetalLayer is one of the classes not defined for the simulator.

Comment: I can't find `CAMetalDrawable` on the simulator (Xcode 8.3.3, osX 10.12). Anyone tried Xcode 9?

Comment: Is there any option to silent this error while i am building in simulator?

Comment: @souvickcse , with Metal, *there is no simulator*. You must tether a device, end of story !  That's the deal!   I guess they really mean it with "Metal"  :)

Comment: My god how utterly retarded. Why bother shipping a simulator at all?

Comment: I know. In some cases for me it was worth writing a low fidelity OpenGL codepath _just_ to keep the simulator working, but now it's deprecated...

Comment: Yay. I just upgraded to macOS10.15beta4 + Xcode11beta4. Now the simulator can run my iOS Metal app!!!

Comment: Are you importing `QuartzCore`?

Answer (score 2):

If your app has a fallback or mode that doesn't depend on Metal, and you want to compile your app for the simulator, you can do something like this:

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
// dummy, do-nothing view controller for simulator
class ViewController: UIViewController {

}
#else
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var device: MTLDevice! = nil
    var metalLayer: CAMetalLayer! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        metalLayer = CAMetalLayer()
        ...
    }

}
#endif
```

Then your code will at least compile for both device and simulator, which can ease your non-Metal development.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem may appear if you name your XCode project "Metal".

In that case compiler will be confused and you'll receive the same error message.

Comment: I doubt you get the same error as the OP has stated?

Comment: @trojanfoe you can easily recheck it. Error is exactly the same